relation between one table to another table in C# But I have more than one propertt in child table
I want to create a survey form, In this form I will get user Information like Name and Ip and .. also I have 10 question that will show below of the form after fileds for userInformations, ok, the options that user will answer are the same for each Question EX: Good,Med , Bad.
I sore Options in table with name PollingScore and another table is for two thinks 1- showing Questions and 2- store answer of user.
Describe More:
In below I will show two tables One for Polling score that has 3 row :good: Med, Bad and the second Model that show information and when user save data will get data and save them on this
public class Polling1
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public Gender Gender { get; set; }
public int GenderId { get; set; }
public Grade Grade { get; set; }
public int Graded { get; set; }
public string Subject { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public string Text { get; set; }
public string UserIp { get; set; }
public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
public DateTime? CustomCreateDate { get; set; }
public bool ReadIt { get; set; }
public bool Answer { get; set; }
public string Mobile { get; set; }
public string NCode { get; set; }
public string SORARank { get; set; }
public string StudyField { get; set; }
[Display(Name ="Question1")]
public int AUDLScore { get; set; }
[Display(Name ="Question2")]
public int LSCDScore { get; set; }
[Display(Name ="Question3")]
public int LSAERPScore { get; set; }
[Display(Name ="Question4")]
public int LSTRScore { get; set; }
[Display(Name ="Question5")]
public int QANewsScore { get; set; }
[Display(Name ="Question6")]
public int SERScore { get; set; }
[Display(Name ="Question7")]
public int LSRDIPScore { get; set; }
[Display(Name ="Question8")]
public int LSRAQSFLScore { get; set; }
[Display(Name ="Question9")]
public int LSLHAndGERScore { get; set; }
[Display(Name ="Question10")]
public string TrackingCode { get; set; }

}

and PollingOptions
public class PollingOptions
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public int Score { get; set; }
public ICollection<Polling> Pollings { get; set; }
 }

each text of question I will show with [Display(name="Question.")] attrebute that will show in form and all property that ended with "...score" want to save value only 1 or 2 or 3 ,How can I make  a good relation between these two tables
